# Tracking changed fields without maintaining history

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-design

I have a table named Books which contains some columns.

```
ColumnNames: BookId, BookName, BookDesc, xxx
```

I want to track changes for certain columns. **I don't have to maintain history of old value and new value. I just want to track that value is changed or not.**

What is the best way to achieve this?

1) Create Books table as:

```
ColumnNames: BookId, BookName, BookName_Changed_Flag, BookDesc, BookDesc_Changed_Flag, 
xxx, xxx_Changed_Flag?
```

2) Create a separate table Books_Change_Log exactly like Books table but only with track change columns as:

```
ColumnNames: BookId, BookName_Changed_Flag, BookDesc_Changed_Flag, xxx_Changed_Flag?
```

Please advise.

--Update--

There are more than 20 columns in each table. And each column represents a certain element in UI. If a column value is ever changed from its original record, i need to display the UI element that represents the column value in different style. Rest of the elements should appear normal.

Comment: Do you need a record of every time a row gets changed or just need to know that it's been changed at some point ever in the history of the row?

Comment: i need to know which column values has ever changed. I need to know that for each column so that i can do UI changes for that particular field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to use a bitfield in TSQL (for updates and reads)

Set the bitfield to default to 0 at start (meaning no changes) you should use type int for up to 32 bits of data and bigint for up to 64 bits of data.

To set a bit in a bit field use the `|` (bit OR operator) in the update statement, for example

```
UPDATE table 
SET field1 = 'new value', bitfield = bitfield | 1

UPDATE table 
SET field2 = 'new value', bitfield = bitfield | 2
```

etc for each field use the 2 to power of N-1 for the value after the `|`

To read a bit field use `&` (bit AND operator) and see if it is true, for example

```
SELECT field1, field2,
       CASE WHEN (bitfield & 1) = 1 THEN 'field1 mod' ELSE 'field1 same' END,
       CASE WHEN (bitfield & 2) = 2 THEN 'field2 mod' ELSE 'field2 same' END
FROM table
```

note I would probably not use text since this will be used by an application, something like this will work

```
SELECT field1, field2,
        CASE WHEN (bitfield & 1) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [field1flag],
        CASE WHEN (bitfield & 2) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [field2flag]
FROM table
```

or you can use != 0 above to make it simple as I did in my test below

---

[Have to actually test to not have errors, click for the test script](https://raw.github.com/gist/1846338/68eee42daa47e200776144aa9192b145ba547485/BitField.SQL)

---

original answer:

If you have less than 16 columns in your table you could store the "flags" as an integer then use the bit flag method to indicate the columns that changed.  Just ignore or don't bother marking the ones that you don't care about.

Thus if flagfield BOOLEAN AND 2^N is true it indicates that the Nth field changed.

Or an example for max of N = 2

0 - nothing has changed (all bits 0)

1 - field 1 changed     (first bit 1)

2 - field 2 changed (second bit 1)

3 - field 1+2 changed (first and second bit 1)

see this link for a better definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

Comment: Your solution looks good but i am not sure on the number of columns i may have in each table. Also can you point me to any blog entry where i can see the implementation and understand it little better?

Comment: I'll write it up for you in a few minutes -- you can actually go as many as 64 columns if you use bitint.

Comment: Also, if you need more than 16 columns, you can have more than one flagfield.  The thing I'm not getting is the 'changed' marker.  It represents a field being changed at least once since it was created?  Or do they need a timestamp stored so they know when each value changed?

Comment: only need to know if the field was ever changed since it was created. Which field was changed when is not important here.

Comment: @Asdfg - see my example code above, I believe this is exactly what you need and super simple to use, efficient in space.

Comment: Cool. I am trying to see how it works. datatype for bitfield shud be Int? What shud i insert in it when the record gets inserted for the first time? NULL?

Comment: It should start at 0 and be type int or bigint.

Comment: I love your solution. Somehow i am not able to implement it. It doesnt update the bitfield values in the update statement. I guess i am missing something but i will post it as a question tomorrow and you can see where am i going wrong here. I can say this is the best thing i learned today.

Comment: @Asdfg - that is what I get for not testing, making fixes now.

Comment: @Hogan : Thank you. Great solution. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a log table that stores the BookId and the date of the change (you don't need those other columns - as you stated, you don't need the old and new values, and you can always get the current value for name, description etc. from the Books table, no reason to store it twice). Unless you are only interested in the last time it changed. You can populate the log table with a simple for update trigger on the books table. For example with the new information you've provided:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.BookLog
(
  BookID INT PRIMARY KEY,
  NameHasChanged BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  DescriptionHasChanged BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
  --, ... 18 more columns
);

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.CreateBook
ON dbo.Books FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT dbo.BookLog(BookID) SELECT BookID FROM inserted;
END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.ModifyBook
ON dbo.Books FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE t SET 
        t.NameChanged = CASE WHEN i.name <> d.name 
          THEN 1 ELSE t.NameChanged END,
        t.DescriptionChanged = CASE WHEN i.description <> d.description 
          THEN 1 ELSE t.DescriptionChanged END,
           --, 18 more of these assuming all can be compared with simple <> ...
    FROM dbo.BookLog AS t
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON i.BookID = t.BookID
    INNER JOIN deleted AS d  ON d.BookID = i.BookID;
END
GO
```

Comment: Anyone care to explain the DV?

Comment: I need to know if Name is changed or not. If name is not changed and only description is changed, i need to notify user on UI that Description is changed but not the name. May be display that one field in Red color and not-changed fields in default color.

Comment: SQL Server can't respond to data changes and send color flags to the application, unless you manually raise an error and catch it in your app (or send data back from the stored procedure that is attempting the update). It is not clear to me if you're trying to prevent or just audit such changes. The trigger above assumes the latter.

Comment: I have updated the question. You have almost understood it except that there are like 20 columns in each table and i need to track if value in column1 changed then display the corresponding UI element in different style. If column2 value is changed then display some other UI element in different style like wise. So when i do "Select", i can grab these _Changed_Flag fields for each column and apply business logic to them

Comment: @Asdfg Try now please. I've updated the answer again based on more information you've provided. Note that until the insert trigger is in place you'll need to populate the booklog table manually for all books that already exist. I hope you'll be able to write the query against the BookLog table with the right business logic to reflect the history status in your UI.

Comment: @AaronBertrand : You are right. Thats what my second option was in the question. I just needed the opinion but you also gave the implementation. Thanks a lot. I am also trying to understand Hogan's answer as it looks i can do it without creating a separate table or 20 _Change_Flag columns if i understand his answer correctly.

Comment: The benefit of using the extra table and the trigger is that your existing modules don't have to change (except for the query that obtains the history status of course). If you store an int in the table to hold the flags, apart from being much more cumbersome to read and debug, you have to change all of your insert / update queries (which may be in stored procedures or may be ad hoc in app(s)) to deal with those. You could update the flag in a trigger as well but I'll still go back to the readability / troubleshooting argument. A table with an INT and 20 BIT columns is not going to hurt you.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you don't need it, but sometimes it's just easier to use something off the shelf which does everything, like: http://autoaudit.codeplex.com/

This just adds a few columns to your table and is not nearly as invasive as either of your proposed schemas, and the trigger necessary to track the changes are also generated by the tool.

Answer (score 1):

I can guarantee you that after you deliver this solution, one of the next requests is going to be "show me what it was before".  Just go ahead and have a history table.  That will solve your current problem AND your future problem.  It is a pretty standard design on non-trivial systems.

Answer (score 0):

Put two datetime columns in your table, "created_at" and "updated_at". Default both to current_timestamp. Only ever set the value of updated_at if you are changing the data in the row. You can enforce this with a trigger on the table that checks to see if any of the column values are changing, and then updates "updated_at" if so.

When you want to check if a row has ever changed, just check if updated_at > created_at.

Comment: You might also want to set up triggers to enforce that created_at is never updated once it is set. You can do it from your app logic but in some cases I have found it easier to enforce a rule like this through a trigger.