# Store multiple bit values in a single table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to store some sort of day-of-week scheduling in database, where I can schedule a record (say it represents a task) for a day or multiple days of the week. I need to have it stored in one column so that it's easy to save and retrieve. Then everyday I select records where the schedule  matches the current day of week, something like: get me all records with schedule matches day of week 7.

What came to my mind is a series of 7 bits each one represents a day of the week where 0 means not schedule, and 1 means scheduled. For example: "1111111" for a case of an everyday task, and "1000000" for a task that only runs in the first day of week.

Just to be clear, the record might be scheduled in any combination of days, which I don't know, therefore the only input in the retrieval would be the weekday to search by.

I have two questions here:

1. What's the best way to store this type of data in SQL Server 2008? In a way that allows easy querying depending of the current day of week.
2. What are better alternatives to the above approach. Please I need efficient and easy to implement solutions.

Comment: How is it really easier to crunch the seven bits into one column instead of seven? I would think separate columns would be easier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could store this as a bitfield and then use boolean logic operators to retrieve the values

for example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testBF](
    [field1] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [field2] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [bitfield] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_testBF_bitfield]  DEFAULT ((0))
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Then for selects:

```
SELECT field1, field2,
       CASE WHEN (bitfield & 1) = 1 THEN 'monday ' ELSE '' END + 
       CASE WHEN (bitfield & 2) = 2 THEN 'tuesday ' ELSE '' END +
       CASE WHEN (bitfield & 4) = 4 THEN 'wednesday ' ELSE '' END +
       CASE WHEN (bitfield & 8) = 8 THEN 'thursday ' ELSE '' END +
       CASE WHEN (bitfield & 16) = 16 THEN 'friday' ELSE '' END as [days of week]
FROM testBF
```

To find all days that contain tuesday flag (tuesday is the 2nd bit or 2^1 or 2)

```
SELECT * 
FROM aTable
WHERE (bitfield & 2) = 2
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM aTable
WHERE (bitfield & 2) != 0
```

Note, the template in the second case will work for any bit -- that is for friday (the 5th bit or 2^4 or 16) would be

```
SELECT * 
FROM aTable
WHERE (bitfield & 16) != 0
```

Finally the general case... pass in a number (1 for monday) you get

```
SELECT * 
FROM aTable
WHERE (bitfield & POWER(2,@inNumOfWeekday-1)) != 0
```

---

This seems like a lot of work to me, when you could just save it as 5 (or 7 bit fields) but that is how you could do it.

For more examples look at the gist I wrote for another question:

https://gist.github.com/1846338

and the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9302106/215752

Comment: Let's say I want to schedule for monday AND tuesday at the dame time, how to encode it in the bitfield, and how can I query it properly?

Comment: Queries I show in my other answer, as above monday and tuesday is `3` or `1 | 2`.  Wikipedia explains better than I ever would : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

Comment: I agree Hogan. The bit math would work, but seems to be overkill and will most likely confuse others. All possible combinations could fit into 1 tinyint (1 byte) column, which would be approximately the same as 7 bit columns, so there's really no storage advantage to either decision.

Comment: There's still something I'm missing here, forgive my ignorance, but the input in the select query will be a single value (1 to 7) representing the day of week, let's day we pass 1 for monday. What I need is to retrieve all records that has monday checked or schedulesd,  whether it was alone or with any combination of days. What your solution seems to do is bring me the records based on provided combination, while all I can provide to the query is the current day.

Comment: I think the last example is wrong for TSQL. In TSQL, ^ is the bitwise exclusive or, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190277.aspx , not power, which I think you were intending. In TSQL, you have to use the POWER function, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174276.aspx .

Comment: @shriop -- interesting... I did test this code 4 years ago.  I don't have a MS SQL server right now so I can't.  If you can actually test -- just edit the answer if it is now wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about a "bit mask". These are handy devices as you can apply binary math on them to easily check the values, but they do take a little setup. To expand on that a little more it would look something like this.

```
-- You will want to work with constants
DECLARE @Mon INT, @Tue INT, @Wed INT, @Thu INT, @Fri INT, @Sat INT, @Sun INT

SET @Mon = POWER(2,0) -- 1
SET @Tue = POWER(2,1) -- 2
SET @Wed = POWER(2,2) -- 4
SET @Thu = POWER(2,3) -- 8
SET @Fri = POWER(2,4) -- 16
SET @Sat = POWER(2,5) -- 32
SET @Sun = POWER(2,6) -- 64

-- Set Monday and Wednesday
UPDATE T SET Schedule = @Mon | @Wed

-- Find all tasks scheduled on Tuesday
SELECT * FROM T WHERE Schedule & @Tue = @Tue

-- Find all tasks scheduled on Tuesday and Saturday
SELECT * FROM T WHERE Schedule & @Tue | @Sat = @Tue | @Sat
```

Comment: While you can add single selectors as you have done, it is much safer to OR them.  For example `(@Tue + @Sat) + (@Tue + @Mon)` looks like it will work given your examples, but it will fail.  However, `(@Tue | @Sat) | (@Tue | @Mon)` works fine.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to test this out sometime. Bit masks are fun, but I have yet to have a need to create one in SQL.

Comment: Grab the gist in my answer and you can see it in action!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by easy querying. It is all easy once you wrap it in a function. An option for easy ad hoc querying might be to have easily readable string fields and use some string manipulation processes work it out. Example:

```
UPDATE T SET Schedule = 'M|W|H'

SELECT * FROM T WHERE CHARINDEX(Schedule, 'M') > -1
```

Comment: I like your string manipulation solution, maybe with a little variation: adding number of weekday instead of letters, without the need of delimiters. Even though priority goes to the more efficient approach. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

From the title, I was led here with a situation of having existing bit fields in a table and needing to convert to a single integer field.

In following the example of days-of-week, let's say have 7 individual bit fields that you want to convert into a (bit-mask) integer field named Schedule:

```
UPDATE T
SET Schedule = Mon * POWER(2,0) +
               Tue * POWER(2,1) +
               Wed * POWER(2,2) +
               Thu * POWER(2,3) +
               Fri * POWER(2,4) +
               Sat * POWER(2,5) +
               Sun * POWER(2,6)
```