# Query for recurring day

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have two table Bus and Recurring. I would like to search the bus on specified date. If search date is fall into Monday, show the bus and if search date fall into Wednesday, don't show.

I would like to know how to create a query using LINQ to EF.

```
Bus
===
Id   Name   From      To         DepartTime ArrivalTime, RecurringId
-------------------------------------------------------------------
01    Bus1  Yangon    Mandalay   20:00      4:00         01
```

Recurring:

```
Id  Mon Tue Web Thu Fri Sat Sun
--------------------------------
01  Y   Y   N   Y   N   Y   N
```

Comment: You can keep it as bit mask as a field of the Bus table itself. For instance, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643491/store-multiple-bit-values-in-a-single-table-column

Comment: This isn't actually a question, it's a request for someone to code something for you.  I think these sorts of questions shouldn't be on stackoverflow.  You should at least have a crack at it yourself, create a database, some tables, an attempt before asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your tables indicates information about a specific date. I assume therefore you want the following...

```
select * 
from 
    Bus as B
    inner join Recurring as R on R.Id == B.Id
where
    R.Mon = 1
```

...all the buses that run on a Monday. The same thing in LINQ to EF would be...

```
Bus[] buses = (from b in context.Bus
               join r in context.Recurring on r.id = b.id
               where r.Mon
               select b).ToArray();
```