# Bitwise AND operator with varbinary column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008, I have a `varbinary(32)` column that represents up to 256 attributes.  I need to be able to identify where a specific attribute is not selected.

For example, attribute 15 gets stored as

```
0x0080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Attributes 14 and 15 gets stored as

```
0x00C0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

So knowing 0x00C000... has attribute 15, I thought I could query using the bitwise `AND` operator to return all rows with attribute 15 turned on:

```
select * from table where varbinaryCol & 32768 > 0
```

But this returns 0 rows.  The table has at least one row with attribute 14 AND 15 turned on and at least one row with only attribute 15 turned on.  I was expecting a minimum of 2 rows to be returned by that query.

What am I missing?

EDIT

Here are further examples of the value of the column with various bits flipped:

```
0:
0x0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

32:
0x0000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

64:
0x0000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

96:
0x0000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

So it looks like there are 8 separate hex values stored in this 64-byte hex string?

Comment: I answered something similar a while ago -- maybe it helps you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9643602/215752

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store multiple bit values in a single table column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643491/store-multiple-bit-values-in-a-single-table-column)

Comment: @Hogan, that duplicate question is not the same. Here the problem is that type is `varbinary`, not `int`. In SQL Server [bitwise operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx) don't work with two `varbinary` values, one of them has to be `int`. You'll have to split the long `varbinary` into 4 byte chunks using `SUBSTRING` and then apply bitwise operators. OR write your CLR function that works with `varbinary`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the type is `varbinary`, not `int`.

In SQL Server [bitwise operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx) don't work with two `varbinary` values, one of them has to be `int` (or `smallint`, `tinyint`, `bit`).

You'll have to split the long `varbinary` into 4 byte chunks using `SUBSTRING` and then apply bitwise operators with `int` bitmask.

Alternatively, you could write CLR function that works with two `varbinary` values.

---

Apart from that, you need to pay attention to how binary values are stored. What is the [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your `32768` bitmask value.

It looks like your `varbinary` value uses different endianness to what SQL Server uses. Very easy to see:

```
SELECT cast(32768 as binary(32))
```

returns

```
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000
```

So, your `varbinaryCol & 32768` compares

```
0x0080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
with
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 32768 = 2^15, however in binary that's the 16th flag because 2^0 = 1.

I would also recommend you use the power function in tsql to represent these numbers, so that someone coming along behind you doesn't have to do the binary translation.

```
SELECT POWER(2,15); -- 32768
```

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation.  I did realize that 2^0 = 1 and in this system, that's recognized as attribute 0.  So rows without attributes will have this column set to

0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: do you know the rows that have 15 turned on? if so, make the select filter to just those two rows using id's or whatever, and in the select also return the result of varbinaryCol & 32768 and see what it is. you'll be able to troubleshoot from there.

Comment: I followed your suggestion, but strangely the (varbinaryCol & 32768) is 0.
[Here's a screenshot](http://imgur.com/qLJmfyz)

Comment: that's what I expected. now do me a favor and see what varbinaryCol & 16384 is.

Comment: please paste here the value returned for varbinaryCol, and what flags you think are set for that column. I'm trying to make sense of the value I see in your screenshot. it doesn't really look right to me. it looks to me like you have flag 23 set. I also think you only need a varbinary(4) to hold possible values for 256 flags, not a varbinary(32).

Comment: The value in varbinaryCol is 0x0080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: I see your edits to the original question. unless someone has some brilliant idea, I think you're going to have to parse the section out of the varbinary prior to doing the binary math, because that number is too large to sit in an int, which the binary math works on.

Comment: That did it!  I was trying substring to pare it down and that wasn't cutting it.  I don't even want to think of how I'd do this for bits 96 and 128, for example.  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `()` -- I think that you might have an order of operations issue

```
select * 
from table 
where (varbinaryCol & 32768) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I have tried that and get the same results.