# store two values in one DB column

Tags: c#

I have `bit` column `Title` where I store value of `Title` visibility property.
Now I need to store value of `Title` mandatory/required property and I don't want to create any extra columns in DB for that.

So, can I store two bit values in one column?
Maybe I need to change type of this column to `number` to use bitwise operators somehow.
And how can I get/set property values?

The simplest way for me for now - change `Title` type to `string` and store values something like "false|true", but I want to find better way to do that.

Comment: Why would you not create a new column for the new property??

Comment: Because I have about 20 columns like `Title`

Comment: You can use single bit column to store data, like if we have 0 for false and 1 for true, then title column will have 1 and other column will have 0 So the combinations would be 10, you can extract this in c#. or you can use Enum for the same instead. Does this help ?

Comment: Well you will result to a hack, so you can either make it a number as you say and map different values to different meaning. 0 = not visible, not require, 1 = visible, not require, 2 = not visible but required, 3 = visible and required, or you can put them in a string as you say, and seperate them with a delimiter.... nothing would qualify as a good way to make it work, since you will result to using hacks anyway.... I would suggest just putting your new property in a new column and dont bother with the columns count

Comment: @VikrantMore Could you explain please more: how can I use Enum? What combinations? And how can I use these combinations?

Comment: Refer [This link For more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9643602/4373895). The same we can do C# side.

Comment: As long as you need to store multiple true/false values, you can change the column type to byte, smallint,int or bigint and use flags approach. For each bit of the number will represent a true/false state. for instance decimal 3 will be 0011 in binary. Where least significant bit (right hand) is 1 meaning visible and the second one also 1 could mean mandatory.

Comment: Can you demonstrate how it will be in c# get/set value. Not sure I'm strong in bitwise operations