# Update one certain bit in a bitmask field (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, bitmap, locking

I have an `int` column containing 8 bits in my SQL Server database. How can I update certain bit without affecting others?

For example, I have a value

```
11010000
```

and I want to set bit1 and bit2 to 1, so it would become

```
11010011
```

Looked through bitwise operators but couldn't find proper solution.

My goal is not only to update certain bit, but also to avoid database locks.

So when transaction1 updates bit1 in a certain record, another transaction2 could update bit2 in the same field of the same record at the same time.

Is this possible? Or is using 8 separate `bit` columns the only way?

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643491/store-multiple-bit-values-in-a-single-table-column

Comment: It isn't possible to allow two different transactions to have an update lock on the same **row**  so neither a single bitmap column or 8 bit columns will allow that. If this is really necessary you would have to split it out into 8 rows

Comment: No - you are not setting "bytes". You are setting "bits" - that is why it is called a bit flag. The entire flag itself is defined as an int which, in turn, occupies 4 bytes. Each byte consists of 8 bits - which means your flag contains 4 * 8 (32) bits - of which you are using just a few. You really need to understand the difference between bits and bytes to be successful in writing code - esp if you need to manipulate bits.

Comment: @SMor Of course I know the difference and started message with 'bit'. Fixed typos, thank you

Comment: Even you use 8 separate 8 bit columns it is not achievable because SQL Server locks the data by row, not by column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pseudo-bitset value is when you have an integer or string that, when selected or printed, looks like a bitset. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @bits varchar(8) = '1010'

SELECT Right(8, REPLICATIE('0', 8) + @bits

Value returned: 00001010
```

For this type of bitset, you need to remember that you are not setting the bits, but are representing the bits instead, and you need to set the representation of the bits in the same way.  For example, the function below can be used to set bits in a string representation of your bitstring:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SetBitInString 
    (
    @Source char(8), 
    @Position int,
    @Action char(1) = 'S',
    @Value bit = NULL
    )
RETURNS Char(8)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @work Char(8) = '00000000'
    SET @work = Right(@work + ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(@Source)), ''), 8)
    SET @Work = 
        CASE @Action
            WHEN 'S'-- Set
                THEN Stuff(@Work, @Position, 1, '1')
            WHEN 'R' -- Reset
                THEN Stuff(@Work, @Position, 1, '0')
            WHEN 'X' -- XOR value with position
                THEN STUFF(@Work, @Position, 1, CAST(CAST(SubString(@Work, @Position, 1) as int) ^ ISNULL(@Value, 0) as CHAR(1)))
            WHEN 'Q'
                THEN '1'
            ---- add other options as needed - this is a quick example.
            ELSE @Action
        END
    IF (@Action = @Work)
        RAISERROR('Bad Action (%s) Submitted', 13, 1, @Action)

    RETURN @Work
END
```

Reading a bit is a simple SUBSTRING. Constants can be defined for the meaning of each bit (e.g. `DECLARE @ShowTotalPrice = 4   -- The 4th bit is the Show Total Price flag`)

This should give you enough to go on if you want to use this style of setting, where the displayed value is your bitset represented in 1s and 0s.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for are the Bitwise operations.  To always turn on the proper bit, use a bitwise OR. So, to turn on bits 1 and 2 (total value = 3), use an statement like this (assumes the value in @value is 208, or 11010000 binary):

```
SET @value = @value | 3
-- or, the alternate form
SET @value |= 3
```

Other operators are the Bitwise AND (`SET @value = @value & 3`), and the bitwise NOT (`SET @Value = @value ~ 3`), and the Bitwise XOR (`SET @value = @value ^ 3`).

That said, having eight `bit` fields is easier logically for a new programmer. I don't need to find something special to see that the field `ShowCurrencySymbol` is the flag for showing a currency symbol, as opposed to finding out what the fifth bit in a byte does. And, since the fields are compacted internally so that eight one-bit, non-nullable fields = one byte of space used (adding NULL takes two bits per bit).

Finally, you can't have two transactions simultaneously update a field on the same row.  While one update is occurring, the row will be locked, preventing the other update from processing. If you really want something like this, you will have to use a much more expansive method - a separate BitValues or Flags table, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Flags (
    RowID int not null,
    FlagName varchar(16) Not Null,
    BitValue bit not null,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Flags PRIMARY KEY (RowID, FlagName)
    );
```

Then you read and write your flags from this table separate from the row.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. As example, value '10000111'. I need to change byte 5 so it would be like '10010111'. But when i try   "@value | 16" I get '10000127'. Now I see that maybe I've had to use CAST .  Anyway, I've already got that SQL will lock the row anyway. So, yes, different table looks the only way. Thank you.

Comment: To toggle a bit, use the XOR, not the OR option. Also, ... ah, you are storing a DECIMAL value trying to store the bits, not using an integer to store the actual bits (so that, if you want the value to be 00010000 to be returned, not 16, if the fifth bit is the only bit set) - that's a different set of update code, and you would use a pseudo-bitset. See below:

Comment: Type of this column is "int". It contains '10000111' and I'm trying to change it to '10010111' (change one sybmbol in the middle and keep other symbols same)

Comment: Then you shouldn't be working with bits at all. You would do this by checking the value in that position of the int and changing that value to be exactly the same. Something like `IF Substring(CAST(@val as varchar(8)), 5, 1) = '0' THEN Set @val = @val + 10000`. However, it is actually easier to do this with a CHAR(8) field than with an INT. You can store the value as an INT, but you should work with it as a CHAR(8), especially if leading zeroes are important (e.g. 00000001 - the INT would only show 1). Added answer coming soon.